# Is there a key for the map icons in game?

Tags: hollow-knight

I bought lots of markers for my map from the nice bug lady in Dirtmouth but I can't actually remember what most of them are for and there doesn't seem to be a key or legend that I can see on the map or in the journal.

I could just look them up on my phone but I was hoping for an quicker in game way to check them without stopping playing. Plus most of the time I am playing is during air travel so I have no internet access to look them up anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Yes, there is an in-game key for map icons

- Open the full-screen map page by double tapping the quick map button.

  - PC: <kbd>Tab</kbd>, Xbox: <kbd>LB</kbd>, PS4: <kbd>L1</kbd>, Switch: <kbd>L</kbd>
- Use the "pins" button to toggle showing or hiding the map pins & key

  - PC: <kbd>P</kbd>, Xbox: <kbd>Y</kbd>, PS4: <kbd>△</kbd>, Switch: <kbd>X</kbd>

[image: Map Screen]

<sub>[Screenshot via bapanada](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U36mt4GAPOo)</sub>

Answer (score 14):

#### Yes, there is!

These are actually called Map Pins, and they are sold by Iselda in Dirtmouth. You must own the pins before they will show up in the map legend, and a [full list is located in the Hollow Knight wiki.](https://hollowknight.wiki/w/Map_and_Quill#Map_Pins) To open the legend on your map, [refer to Stevoisak's answer:](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361332/is-there-a-key-for-the-map-icons-in-game/361360#361360)

> - Open the full-screen map page by double tapping the quick map button.

- PC: <kbd>Tab</kbd>, Xbox: <kbd>LB</kbd>, PS4: <kbd>L1</kbd>, Switch: <kbd>L</kbd>

> - Use the "pins" button to toggle showing or hiding the map pins & key

- PC: <kbd>P</kbd>, Xbox: <kbd>Y</kbd>, PS4: <kbd>△</kbd>, Switch: <kbd>X</kbd>

An example of some can be seen below:

[image]

> Map pins are used to mark locations on the map. Many are sold by Iselda in Dirtmouth, while others will have their unlock condition noted. The 4 markers sold by Iselda can be placed on the map on the inventory screen. Each set contains 6 markers.

In addition, there are vendor pins that, much like the map pins, mark the vendors on your map.

[image]

---

### These aren't the map markers I'm looking for?

Now, if you are talking about map markers, [these are seperate mechanics](https://hollowknight.wiki/w/Map_and_Quill#Mapping_Tools) that allow you to mark a location on the map for yourself. They have no actual in-game meaning tied to them.
[image]

Answer (score -3):

Sadly, no. There is no in-game map legend that will tell you what exactly every icon means. You will have to check them online or save a complete legend for offline perusal.

I had the exact same issue on my first playthrough and couldn't find any one-stop easy to read legend so if you do, please link to it.

Comment: [There is an in-game map legend](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/361360/181240). Open the map screen in the inventory and press P to show/hide the map key.

Comment: It must be a weird mapping of my xbox controller through the Steam Link then. I had to use Back to display the map and no button worked to display the legend. Thanks for letting me know, I'll see how I can fix that should I start a new playthrough.